# Trying to update db using put mapping

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, postman

I am writing a rest controller that updates a field in my database. However when I'm trying to send the request through postman to update the fields,I'm getting Request method 'PUT' not supported error.Please help.Thanks in advance.I am using spring for developing the backend.

Here is my repo:

```
 @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Report c SET c.name= :nameWHERE c.id = :id")
    void updateName(@Param("id") long id, @Param("name") String name);
```

My rest Controller:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}/{name}")
public void updateName(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @PathVariable("name") String name)
{
   repository.updateName(id,name);

}
```

Postman request

```
http://localhost:8080/reports?id=1&name=test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url should used path params not request params and should look like

```
http://localhost:8080/reports/1/test
```